# Observe changes in any property of any member of an array

Tags: arrays, swift, key-value-observing, didset

I have an array which stores objects of a class:

```
class Apple {

    var color = "Red"

}

let myApple = Apple()

var apples = [Apple]()

apples.append(myApple)

// Func should be called here
myApple.color = "Blue"

let otherApple = Apple()

// Func should not be called here, 
// because otherApple is not a member of apples array
otherApple.color = "Green"
```

I want to run a function when any property of any member of "apples" array has changed. When calling this function, I need to pass the item of the array whose property is changed as a parameter.

I thought of using `didSet` on color property, but in that case function is called when otherApple's property is changed too. This is not what I want. I only want to run the function when a property of a member of the array has changed. If it is not a member, the function should not run.

Using `didSet`, running the function in any case, and checking membership in the beginning of the function might be an idea but I feel this is not a good way.

How can I properly achieve this with Swift?

Edit: Apple's guide for [Using Key-Value Observing in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift)

Comment: I would use a reactive programming framework like RxSwift or Apple's new Combine (although that's only available to iOS 13+ and macOS Catalina, so it's not really usable yet). Make `color` an observable property, and subscribe to it by whatever code is interested in being notified of its changes

Comment: Have you used `didSet` on `apples` `array`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `observer` to all the `Apple` objects that you're adding in `apples` `array`.

First of all create a property named `observers` of type `[NSKeyValueObservation]` at class level, i.e.

```
var observers = [NSKeyValueObservation]()
```

Now, create a method that will append new `Apple` instances in `apples array` and add `observer` to it,

```
func addNewApple(_ apple: Apple) {
    observers.append(apple.observe(\.color, options: [.new], changeHandler: { (apple, changes) in
        if let newValue = changes.newValue {
            print(newValue)
        }
    }))
    apples.append(apple)
}
```

To observe a property of an object, that must be marked it `@objc dynamic`. So, the `Apple` definition goes like,

```
class Apple: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var color = "Red"
}
```

Now, you can use it as described below,

```
let myApple = Apple()
self.addNewApple(myApple)
myApple.color = "Blue"
```

Combining all the bits and pieces, the whole code can be written like,

```html
class VC: UIViewController {
    var apples = [Apple]()
    var observers = [NSKeyValueObservation]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let myApple = Apple()
        self.addNewApple(myApple)
        myApple.color = "Blue"
        
        let otherApple = Apple()
        otherApple.color = "Green"
    }
    
    func addNewApple(_ apple: Apple) {
        observers.append(apple.observe(\.color, options: [.new], changeHandler: { (apple, changes) in
            if let newValue = changes.newValue {
                print(newValue)
            }
        }))
        apples.append(apple)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. Sorry for the delay in accepting the answer.